# Php query regarding 2 FK and 1 Primary Key

Tags: php, sql

In my table internships, I have two foreign keys **id_promoter_internship** and **id_supervisor_internship**. In the table business_contacts I have 1 primary key **id_business**. I'm trying to get data from the business_contacts table which is linked to the internships table. Is the following query correct?

```
       public function update_form_business_contact($name_enterprise){
        $query = "
             SELECT 
                  * 
             FROM business_contacts
                  ,internships 
             WHERE 
                  business_contacts.id_business = internships.id_supervisor_internship 
                  AND internships.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'";     
        $result = $this->_db->query($query);

        # Go through results of teachers
        if($result->rowCount()!=0){
            while($row=$result->fetch()){
                $contact= new businesscontact ( $row->id_business,$row->firstname_business,$row->lastname_business,$row->service_business,$row->function_business,$row->phone_business,$row->phone_secretary_business,$row->mobile_business);
            }
        }
        return $contact;
    }
```

My question is: Does the primary key have to reference both foreign keys? If so how would I do that.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try run this code?

Comment: Yes, I get an "Undefined variable: contact" error. A simple 'SELECT * FROM business_contacts' works so I guess the issue is in my query. @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev

Comment: Is anything common in the two tables, like an `id` for example?

Comment: Does it work when you `select * from busniness_contacts WHERE ... = $variable` to see if its working when you insert a variable

Comment: Internships has id_promoter_internship AND id_supervisor_internships (two foreign keys). Business_contacts has id_business (Primary key) @Chris

Comment: @Stivan Yes it seemed to function with a variable. The issue must be in the query.

Comment: Did you tr your code in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what these are. Can you edit your post and add the output of the query `DESCRIBE business_contacts, internships`?

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the query using join like:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM business_contacts bc
          INNER JOIN internships i ON bc.id_business = i.id_supervisor_internship 
          WHERE internships.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'";
```

Comment: maybe the problem is in the $name_enterprise, remember it has to be the exact STRING value (Case Sensitive), try to echo the value before executing the query!

Comment: and try running the script directly from the server or phpmyadmin if you have it!

Answer (score 0):

If you need both ids then left join twice using both ids:

```
$query = "select
               * 
          from internships i
               left join business_contacts bc  ON bc.id_business = i.id_supervisor_internship
               left join business_contacts bc2 on bc2.id_business = i.id_promoter_internship
          WHERE 
               i.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'";
```

If you need only supervisor id:

```
$query = "select
                   * 
              from internships i
                   left join business_contacts bc  ON bc.id_business = i.id_supervisor_internship
              WHERE 
                   i.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'";
```

If you need only promoter id:

```
$query = "select
                   * 
              from internships i
                   left join business_contacts bc on bc.id_business = i.id_promoter_internship
              WHERE 
                   i.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'";
```

To get use specific parameter in the join:

```
$query = "select
               * 
          from internships i
               left join business_contacts bc  ON bc.id_business = i.id_promoter_internship and i.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'";
```

Comment: It seems to be working I don't get any errors :), however a var_dump displays null for every attribute now. @Stivan

Comment: @JoeSmith Well I don't think 2 joins to that table are necessary. What ids are you looking for supervisor or promoter?

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to use the $name_enterprise (in parameter) to find the line which has the information I'm looking for. Could I possibly upload a picture of both the tables so you understand ? Thanks for your help. @Stivan

Comment: @JoeSmith I understand now. But could you tell me what id you want to join with or do you need both?

Comment: I need id_promoter_internship, I thought I would have to join both as they are both foreign key to 1 id. @Stivan

Comment: @JoeSmith See my last query. "To get specific parameter in join"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111800/discussion-between-stivan-and-joe-smith).